# How to disable print dialog in Chromium?

Tags: delphi, command-line, printing, chromium

There is web page, that has the "Print" button. I load it using DCEF3. If user clicks the button, the Printer selection dialog is shown. I want to disable printing once and for all.
I have been trying to pass command line parameters using the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514606/how-to-mute-the-sound-of-a-delphi-chromium-embedded-tchromium-component).
So, I tried the following:

```
--disable-print-preview
--kiosk
--kiosk-printing
```

But none of them did the trick. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CEF3 doesn't support "silent" printing, that is, printing without a printer selection dialog.

All you can do is :

- Print to a temporal PDF file and then print the PDF file.
- Take a snapshot from the browser and print the bitmap.
- Modify the CEF3 libraries to hide the printer selection dialog.

These functions are much easier to use with [CEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) or [OldCEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/OldCEF4Delphi). To print in a PDF file all you have to do is call TChromium.PrintToPDF and to take a snapshot you need to call TChromium.TakeSnapshot

Not all the Chromium flags or command line switches are supported by CEF3. --kiosk and --kiosk-printing are not supported as you can see [here](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12567#p24126).

You may even have to modify the JavaScript code in that web page to replace the "print" button function with a custom JavaScript extension registered with CEF3. That extension would send a message to the main browser process to print using your custom function.